# React Native : Regarding State and Callback handlers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So I am still learning React Native and I am trying to build a very simple app to understand state, events in React Native.

Here in this app I display a button titled "first" as soon as the app is rendered on the screen.

Upon clicking that button a modal is displayed. This modal contains a button titled "second".

The objective is to hide the modal upon "onPress" of the "second" button.

Thsi is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
}

state = {
  modalVisible: false,
}

 hideModal = () => {
   console.log("Btnpress pressed");
   this.setState({modalVisbile: false});
 }

 showModal() {
   console.log("BtnPress1 pressed");
   this.setState({modalVisible: true});
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="first"
          onPress={this.showModal}
          disabled={this.state.modalVisible} />
        <Modal
          animationType= "slide"
          transparent= {false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        >
        <Button
          title="second"
          onPress={this.hideModal}
          disabled={!this.state.modalVisible}
          />
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

What Happens

a) There are no errors.
b) The app is rendered successfully and display the button "first".
c) When the "first" button is clicked, the second button("second") contained in the modal is rendered as expected.
d) But when the "second" button is clicked the "first" button is not rendered.

**My understanding is that upon "onPress" event on "second" button the below callback is invoked which changes the state.**

```
 onPress={this.hideModal}
```

**After changing that state (which would now be modalVisible = false) the button titled "first" will be rendered. But this is not happening.**

Can some one tell em what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you misspelled visible, if you correct the spelling, it looks like it will work

```
 hideModal = () => {
 console.log("Btnpress pressed");
 this.setState({modalVisible: false}); /*you had modalVisbile*/
 }
```